# For loop sum of numbers between specific dates in array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, date, for-loop, sum

Here is an example of the data from server in JSON format:

```
var infom = {
  "info": [
    {
      "date":"2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "number":"1"
    },
    {
      "date":"2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "number":"2"
    },
    {
      "date":"2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z",
       "number":"3"
    },
    {
      "date":"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "number":"4"
    }
  ]
};
```

1. How can I get the sum of the numbers.

   I have tried:

   ```
   info = infom.info;
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
     inf = info[i];
     n1 = parseInt(inf.number);
     console.log(sum+=n1);
   }
   ```

   This prints the numbers: `1, 3, 6, 10`.

   How can I only get the `10` but not `1, 3, 6`?
2. How can I get the numbers before/after a specific date.*

   For example, sum of the numbers after `2018-10-3`:
   `2 + 1 = 3`

Comment: for the first question you need to move the `console.log` outside the `for` loop. For the second question you need to tuse `.filter` on the array of elements and keep only those whose date is after/before the one you specify, before performing the addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT: Note the comment from [@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) regarding the ability to compare ISO 8601 date strings lexically to avoid issues with [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). See the updated answer below to reflect that comment, the original answer follows for reference.

UPDATE:

The following example removes the date parsing step when compared to the original.

```js
const info = {"info": [{ "date": "2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "1" }, { "date": "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "2" }, { "date": "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "3" }, { "date": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "4" } ] };
const sum = info.info.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc += parseInt(obj.number);
  return acc;
}, 0);

const sumDate = info.info.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (obj.date >= '2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z') {
    acc += parseInt(obj.number);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log('sum', sum);
console.log('sumDate', sumDate);
```

ORIGINAL:

You need to [parse the date strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for comparison and then you can just use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). If you prefer a for loop, see the corrections to your original code with some quick explanation below the snippet (as it applies to just summing all the values - you could modify the for loop with the same principles as seen below in the `reduce` approach).

`sum` below just gets a sum of all the `number` properties in your array of objects (fairly simple example of how to use `reduce`). `sumDate` below adds an `if` statement to compare the `date` properties in your array of objects before including the corresponding `number` in the sum (just hardcoded a date string for 2018-10-3 in the same format as your other data, but you could turn it into a function and pass the date as a parameter as well as determining whether to sum dates before or after the comparison date).

For example:

```js
const info = {"info": [{ "date": "2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "1" }, { "date": "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "2" }, { "date": "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "3" }, { "date": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", "number": "4" } ] };
const sum = info.info.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc += parseInt(obj.number);
  return acc;
}, 0);

const sumDate = info.info.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (Date.parse(obj.date) >= Date.parse('2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z')) {
    acc += parseInt(obj.number);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log('sum', sum);
console.log('sumDate', sumDate);
```

To correct your original for loop attempt, the primary issue was that you were not incrementing your `sum` variable. Also, don't forget to declare the variables you are using with `var` (or even better with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)).

```
var info = info.info;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(info[i].number);
}

console.log(sum);
// 10
```

Comment: "*You need to parse the date strings*", not at all, ISO 8601 format strings can be compared lexically, which avoids the issues of the built-in parser (which the reference you included recommends to avoid).

Comment: @RobG - thanks as always for your guidance. The answer has been edited to highlight the date parsing issue for any future readers.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I only get the 10 but not 1, 3, 6?

Move the *console.log* out of the loop. You can also greatly simplify the code:

```js
var infom = {"info":[
  {"date":"2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z","number":"1"},
  {"date":"2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z","number":"2"},
  {"date":"2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z","number":"3"},
  {"date":"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","number":"4"}
]};

var info = infom.info;
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(info[i].number);
}
console.log(sum);
```

> How can I get the numbers before/after a specific date.*

ISO 8601 format date strings can be compared lexicographically. If the comparison date is provided in the same format, you avoid Date objects and parsing:

```js
var infom = {"info":[
  {"date":"2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z","number":"1"},
  {"date":"2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z","number":"2"},
  {"date":"2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z","number":"3"},
  {"date":"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","number":"4"}
]};

function getSumAfter(data, date) {
  return data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    if (obj.date.localeCompare(date) > 0) {
      acc += +obj.number;
    }
    return acc;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(getSumAfter(infom.info,'2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z')); // 3

// Which can be reduced to
function getSumAfter2(data, date) {
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => obj.date.localeCompare(date) > 0? acc += +obj.number : acc, 0);
}

console.log(getSumAfter2(infom.info,'2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z')); // 3
```

However, the second production might be less maintainable.

You're also using UTC timestamps, so be careful when comparing with "local" dates that might be offset and produce unexpected results.

Comment: var infom = {"info":[ {"date":"2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z","number":"1"}, {"date":"2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z","number":"2", "value":"1"}, {"date":"2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z","number":"3"}, {"date":"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","number":"4"} ]}; What If I want to get the sum after/before the data where it contains the "value" object in it. Is it possible?

Comment: @uhbc—I'd set a flag and only start summing values once an object with a *value* property, or a *value* property with certain value, was found.